# What do I do with a libgdx rectangle collision?

Tags: java, libgdx, android

The edge of the rectangle is not detached

[image]

[image: But if the rectangle is narrowed, it will affect the left and right collision detection]
But if the rectangle is narrowed, it will affect the left and right collision detection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use the same collision math for every type of collision you recognize.  Try using a smaller shape to detect whether the character is level with the ground, and using a larger shape to detect whether the character collides with your other components.

Comment: ok,i think this is the best idea,i will try